# my maven plugin always has touch option in idea

Tags: java, maven

I developed a maven plugin

```
/**
 * Goal which touches a timestamp file.
 *
 * @goal touch
 * @phase process-sources
 */
@Mojo(name = "generate")
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo {
```

in my project i search touch keyword and they are all in comment

in idea  [image]

i want to how to remove it and i run the touch it came to an error